# JMeter WebDriver Sampler: Your connection is not private

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Am trying to collect the performance metrics on Browser (client-side). While launching the url through browser, I get the following message:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEcXd.jpg)

Please find my code below:

[Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSaXk.jpg)

How do I fix this?

Thanks for your support.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing you can "fix" there, because it's the problem with the web application you're testing, either it's [certificate](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/ssl/what-is-an-ssl-certificate/) is self-signed or it's untrusted or something is missing in the chain, in other words you need to "fix" this on on JMeter/Selenium level but on the system under test level.

If you want to "work around" this you can configure your browser to accept insecure certificates, it can be done under "Capabilities Management" tab of your [WebDriver](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/) config element:

[image]

More information on Selenium WebDriver: [What Is Selenium WebDriver?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-selenium-webdriver)